# How to listen for key press in Flutter

Tags: flutter, events, keyboard, keyboard-events

I am trying to detect the physical key press of a button. This button is on a Scanner with Android installed on it, and **the press is registered as a `F16` key.**

I am able to detect key presses but ONLY after first focusing a `TextField`. This is my code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    logger.d("Waiting for initialization...");
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      logger.d("Initialization done");
      ServicesBinding.instance.keyboard.addHandler(_onKey);
    });
  }

  bool _onKey(KeyEvent event) {
    logger.d('onKey called');

    if (event is KeyDownEvent) {
      if (event.physicalKey.debugName == 'F16') {
        logger.d('F16 key pressed');
      }
    } else if (event is KeyUpEvent) {
      if (event.physicalKey.debugName == 'F16') {
        logger.d('F16 key released');
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

I have tried both the normal keyboard listener and the RawKeyboard listener:

```
ServicesBinding.instance.keyboard.addHandler(_onKey);
RawKeyboard.instance.addListener(_onRawKey);
```

The result is always the same. On start-up, nothing is detected when the button is pressed, `_onKey` is NEVER called.

However, if I first press a `TextField` and then press the button, `_onKey` does get called. The interesting part is that this effect is permanent. **If I un-focus the `TextField`, then navigate to another page and back, `_onKey` still gets called correctly**. Even after restarting in Flutter.

It only does not work if I kill the app fully and restart it.

It is as if the keyboard services are sleeping until some even occurs that wakes them up. Does anybody know how I can solve this so that my key presses always get detected?

Comment: you must Wrap your returned(main) widget with `RawKeyboardListener` . did you do it?

Comment: @AshikulIslamSawan I attempted that approach as well, but it also did not work. But even so, from what I understand, the ServiceBinding listeners do not require the RawKeyboardListener widget, in fact they should work always, independently of focus. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following widget as a keyboard listener:

```dart
class SimpleKeyboardListener extends StatefulWidget {
  const SimpleKeyboardListener({
    super.key,
    required this.onF16Pressed,
    required this.child,
  });

  final VoidCallback onF16Pressed;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<SimpleKeyboardListener> createState() => _SimpleKeyboardListenerState();
}

class _SimpleKeyboardListenerState extends State<SimpleKeyboardListener> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    RawKeyboard.instance.addListener(_keyboardCallback);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    RawKeyboard.instance.removeListener(_keyboardCallback);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }

  void _keyboardCallback(RawKeyEvent keyEvent) {
    if (keyEvent is! RawKeyDownEvent) return;

    if (keyEvent.data.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.f16) {
      widget.onF16Pressed();
    }
  }
}
```

Use above widget as following in your UI:

```dart
class SampleComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleComponent({super.key});

  @override
  State<SampleComponent> createState() => _SampleComponentState();
}

class _SampleComponentState extends State<SampleComponent> {
  // change to false, if you navigated to another page or opened a dialog.
  bool listen = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleKeyboardListener(
      onF16Pressed: () {
        if (listen) {
          // do your thing
        }
      },
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. I created a new project from scratch and directly placed your SimpleKeyboardListener around the MaterialApp in my main.dart file.
Unfortunately, the result is exactly the same, absolutely nothing happens when clicking the button. I added a TextField in the main.dart, and after focusing it, your code works. Just a small detail is that this is a physical key, not logical, so the _keyboardCallback method has to be updated.

But the main issue here really is, how come the button press does not get detected on start, but only after focusing a text field.

Comment: @FabianSvensson can you please share your final code? Above widget should work without any focus.